# Mongoose doesn't save model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to define my models and save it to my MONGODB cluster.

everything looks fine, but when I post request to my route to save the `user model` the post request loading process vill no complete :(

This is the Main file :

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DATABASE CONNECTION
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(
  connectionString,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  },
  () => {
    console.log("database connected!");
  }
);

// ROUTES
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
app.use("/", userRoute);

const port = 4040;
app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) console.log(`Listening faild`);
  console.log(`Listening on PORT ${port}`);
});
```

This is my routes/user.js :

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

const User = require("../models/user");

router.post("/reg", (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    phone: req.body.phone,
    pin: req.body.pin,
    fullName: req.body.FullName
  });

  user
    .save()
    .then(data => {
      res.json(data);
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        message: err
      });
      console.log(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this the model of users object :

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = Schema({
  phone: Number,
  pin: Number,
  fullName: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: is the Mongo operation completed successfully? do you see the `data`?

Comment: @YoniMayer Database is connected, and i don't see any collection datas in mongodb atlas .

Comment: did you connect to the DB with `mongoose.connect(<your URI connection>)` ?

Comment: @YoniMayer yes i did.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(req.body) ` before save. And put the other console logs before res.json? Also can you add your main file to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah , i did bro, it responded me the JSON data.

Comment: So, post route responds but you see no document in your users collection?

Comment: yup, it's true.

Comment: Be sure that you are checking the correct database and collection, it must be the database which the application uses.

Comment: So the only problem is database connection?

Comment: @tafhim Did you try it in the mongo shell and see any collections?

Comment: @metalHeadDev I don't use mongo shell, I used MongoDB closter cloud, it was okay before, idk what is the problem now

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `connectionString`.
It should look something like this - `mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...` or in localhost - `mongodb://localhost:27017/database`

Comment: I defined, I just didn't write it here

Comment: Honestly, I can't see any problem. Just check the path in user.js `const User = require("../models/user");`. Apart from that you gotta do yourself, sorry mate.